# luatex cache path not created during texlive 2023 installation

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

I have installed texlive 2023 on my manjaro machine.
When I compile my tex files with luathex I can see the following lines in the output log:

```
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua.gz": nil
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz": nil
luaotfload | db : Index file not writable
luaotfload | db : Failed to save database to disk: nil
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.lua": nil
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc": nil
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache file not writable.)
```

when I run `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFCACHE`
I get `/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var:/home/hafid/.texlive2023/texmf-var`

when I run `luaotfload-tool -u`
I get

```
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua.gz": /home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua.gz: No such file or directory
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz": /home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz: No such file or directory
luaotfload | db : Index file not writable
luaotfload | db : Failed to save database to disk: nil
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.lua": /home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.lua: No such file or directory
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc": /home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc: No such file or directory
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache file not writable.
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.lua": /home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.lua: No such file or directory
luaotfload | cache : Failed to write "/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc": /home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc: No such file or directory
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache file not writable.
```

The question: is it quiet normal that the  directory : `/home/hafid/texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names`
is not created during texlive installation ?

Comment: well the question is why luaotfload-tool can't write the files. Do you have some virus protection that would block ot?

Comment: did you install with the same account you are using? what are the unix file permissions on texmf-var?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No virus protection.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `drwxr-xr-x  7 hafid hafid    4096 21 janv. 08:43 texmf-var`

Comment: so you (only) can write to that directory, work down the tree at what point can you not write luatex-cache/generic/names

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 18 nov.  11:36 luatex-cache` I don't understand how and why `root root` ???!!!

Comment: looks like you did an update as root, you can chown it back to you